# How can I get a row of buttons aligned to the bottom of the hero background image section?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a section with a hero background image, and I want to overlay a row with two buttons towards the bottom of the image, making sure that on smaller screens with less vh the images remain inside the section.  I can get them into the middle of the image but nothing I've found so far gets them pushed down to the bottom.

```css
.herobgimage {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/1200');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id='hero' class='d-flex align-items-center herobgimage'>
  <div class='container mt-0 mt-lg-1'>
    <div class='row pt-sm-3 pt-md-5 pt-lg-5 mt-1 mt-lg-5'>
      <div class='col-lg-12 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center pt-5 order-2 order-lg-1'>
        <div class='d-flex flex-column justify-content-center'>
          <div class='p-md-2'>
            <span class='mr-3'><a href='' class='btn-get-started scrollto'>Get Started</a></span>
            <span><a href='' class='btn-login scrollto'>Sign In</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: With `d-flex`, try `align-content-end` and `justify-content-end` on the button wrapper. I always get them mixed up.

Comment: ^ Sorry, I should have said. You might also have to use `flex-column` with the above so as to flex vertically rather than horizontally.

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet, but I'm not sure it shows the issue. Please revise so it does.